# How to change the color of svg image in img src

Tags: image, svg, colors, src

How to change the color of svg image in img src

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

My codepen channel solve
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Gul-Bahar_1/pen/WNMKYMg)

`filter: invert(.5) sepia(1) saturate(5) hue-rotate(175deg);`

filter color convert hex color
[codepen](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)